# Is there a way to provide custom sounds for omm-writer?

Tags: text-editors

I would like to replace the keyboard sounds in OmmWriter with my own versions. Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no preferences for OmmWriter, anyway inside the application folder (right click, `show package contents`) you have `Contents/Resources/` folder with all the sounds. There you can replace the sounds you want to replace.

I am really looking forward to using OmmWriter preferences, if and when they will be availale. I think it will be a nice feature.